# Can rsync target tar archives instead of filesystems?

Tags: rsync

Rsync out the box allows files on a filesystem to be synchronised with remote files on a filesystem.

Can rsync allow files on a filesystem to be synchronised with a remote files on a remote set of tar archives?

The current problem with rsync is that the target filesystem needs the same users and groups as the source, and to be running as root for the backup to be accurate. If the target system was a tar file, the target need not be root.

Note: this is the opposite question to this: [rsync to/from tar archive](https://superuser.com/questions/1025256/rsync-to-from-tar-archive)

Comment: Why is it the opposite to that question?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. Use `--fake-super` to create backups of privileged metadata to an unprivileged destination.

If the destination is remote, use `-M` to send the option to the remote rsync handler without applying it locally.

```
# rsync -asdfgh -M"--fake-super" /foo normaluser@dst:/backup/foo
```